# "Converting circular structure to JSON" BigQuery Insert from Cloud Function NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to load array of json objects to BigQuery Table from Cloud Function written in NodeJs. I get the error "Converting circular structure to JSON although I dont have any circular references. My code is like following.

I have a function from which I call

```
var num_rows = insertRowsAsStream(data);

res.status(200).send(num_rows);
```

The inserRowsAsStream function is

```
async function insertRowsAsStream(data) {
  // Inserts the JSON objects into my_dataset:my_table.

  // Create a Client
  const bigQuery = new BigQuery({projectID: 'myProject'});

  const datasetId = 'test_data';
  const tableId = 'temp';
  const rows = data;

  // Insert data into a table
  await bigQuery
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .insert(rows);

  return rows.length ;
}
```

data arg which is passed to insertRowsAsStream is of the format. There are no circular references anywhere.

```
[ {"name": "John Doe", "age": 30, "title": "Director"}, {"name": "Jane Doe", "age": 27, "title": "Manager"} ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your function appears to be returning `rows.length`, it is actually returning a Promise that resolves to the value of `rows.length`.  That's because `insertRowsAsStream` is declared `async`, and all `async` functions return a Promise.

What you should do instead is also `await` the result of insertRowsAsStream, assuming that the containing function is also `async`:

```
var num_rows = await insertRowsAsStream(data);
res.status(200).send(num_rows);
```

You might also want to consider sending something other than a number.  Perhaps a JSON object that the caller can easily parse:

```
res.json({ numRows: num_rows })
```

This will let you change the response by adding new properties, without breaking existing clients.

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. I added the await before insertRowsAsStream and also changed to res.json

Comment: But why does the error mention about "Converting circular structure to JSON" while it has to do with await. I am using inline editor to write cloud function which does not show the line number which is throwing error. How do you debug code in inline editor?